# Combination of strings, other variables and regexp in variable declaration

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to move files to other directories with `FileUtils.mv`. I'm trying to define a variable called `name_convention`, which is a mix of strings, other variables and I also want to include a `regexp`, where I'm failing. My code so far:

```
    #these are my other variables already declared from an array
    season = array[11..13]
    episode = array[15..17]

    #and this is my 'name_convention' variable
    name_convention = "friends" + season + episode + "bluray.mkv"
```

Up to here, everything is working fine. Except that between `friends` and `season`, there can be either a `.` or a `_`. For example:

```
    friends_s01e01_bluray.mkv
    friends.s01e01.bluray.mkv
```

I tried to use a regexp, like `/(\.|-)/`, but I got the error: `no implicit conversion of regex into string ruby`

How can I provide the two options to my `name_convention` variable, so that it can be applied to both filenames?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to interpolate a regex into a string, but you need to do the opposite - interpolate the strings into the regex:

```
season = "s01"
episode = "e01"

regex = /friends[\._]#{Regexp.escape(season)}#{Regexp.escape(episode)}.bluray.mkv/

regex.match "friends_s01e01_bluray.mkv"
# => MatchData

regex.match "friends.s01e01_bluray.mkv"
# => MatchData

regex.match "friends-s01e01_bluray.mkv"
# => nil
```

For this particular example (s01 and e01) you don't need the `Regexp.escape` but it's a good idea to include it just in case.

Comment: `MatchData` also behaves a lot like an array, or exactly as one with `to_a`.

Comment: @tadman ah I should have used `match?` for this example instead but I couldn't remember it at the time

Comment: `match?` is great for testing if it matches and not caring about how, while `match` or `scan` or even `String#[]` is great for extracting the matches.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your reply. But what if I then need to use your `regex` variable as a string, for example to create a path to the file? For example `File.join(my_dir, regex)`

Comment: You normally don't use a Regex as a string directly. You usually use it to match, and then convert the match to a string. It's not clear what you're intending here. Are you saying "Can I use a regular expression to filter a directory for matches?"

Comment: @tadman I basically wanted to move files, according to a specific part of the file name, to a given folder using `regexp`, but I just can't. For example: `friends.s01e01_720p_bluray` should be moved to directory `_outcome\s01\e01` and so on. The position of `s01` and `e01` are always the same within the filename. I've managed to create the directories but can't just move the files.

Comment: You have to do this in a few steps @Topa_14. First extract the variables (season, episode, etc) using regex. Then build the destination path using string interpolation. There is maybe a way to do it in one step using  [gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) but I don't know exactly how

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a quick and dirty `sNNeNN` parser, try this:

```rb
def parse_episode(str)
  m = str.match(/\A(.*?)[\-\_\.]?(s\d+)(e\d+)[\-\_\.]?(.*)\z/i)

  # If matched, strip out the first entry which is the complete match
  m&.to_a&.drop(1)
end
```

Where this produces results like:

```rb
parse_episode('snowpiercer-s01e01-stream')
# => ["snowpiercer", "s01", "e01", "stream"]
parse_episode('s01')
# => nil
parse_episode('wilford')
# => nil
parse_episode('simpsons_S04E12_monorail')
# => ["simpsons", "S04", "E12", "monorail"]
parse_episode('simpsons.S04E12')
# => ["simpsons", "S04", "E12", ""]
```